# what exactly is the "order"-parameter in pandas interpolation?

Tags: python, pandas, mathematics, parameter, interpolation

what exactly is the "order"-parameter in pandas interpolation?

it is mentioned in the doc:

```
‘nearest’, ‘zero’, ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘spline’, ‘barycentric’, ‘polynomial’: Passed to scipy.interpolate.interp1d. These methods use the numerical values of the index. Both ‘polynomial’ and ‘spline’ require that you also specify an order (int), e.g. df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=5).
```

Answer (score 1):

The `order` argument simply refers to the order of the function that is used when interpolating values. As the documentation mentiones, you only need to provide a value for the `order` argument when you are using either a polynomial or spline for the interpolation. The value then simply refers to the order (or degree) of the polynomial or spline that is used, e.g. a second or third order polynomial. You can find some more info on the documentation of the underlying `scipy.interpolate` functions that are called, which are [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) for the polynomial and [`UnivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) for the spline.

Comment: But if polynomial interpolation has to fit all the datapoints onto a 3rd degree polynomial, how is it supposed to do that if my datacolumn has 1mio values?